# Unable to git-clone new application to windows machine

Tags: git, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I am creating a new `Nodejs` project in openshift.  however, upon creation by `rhc` i am unable to clone my created git repo to my windows machine even after deleting retrying, here is the message I see in `rhc`, Cheers ! :

```
Application URL: [url]
Issues:
1. We were unable to clone your application's git repo - Unable to clone
your repository. Called Git with: git clone [ssh URL]

Steps to complete your configuration:
1. Clone your git repo
$ rhc git-clone [application name]

If you continue to experience problems after completing these steps,
you can try destroying and recreating the application:

$ rhc app delete  [application name]--confirm
```

Comment: Hi, you can clone your application throug 'html' URL, try once. 'git clone htmlURL'. in this process you have to provide your git credentials

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the rhc setup command?  Try checking out the developer portal which will help you get setup with ruby, git, and the rhc tool: https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-client-tools.html#windows

Answer (score 0):

Run "rhc setup" from your Command Prompt (cmd) -

**When installing Ruby, be sure to use Version 1.9.3, instead of the most recent (for Windows).**

That will prompt you to login to OpenShift from cmd - once you've authenticated your account, you can generate SSH keys and automatically upload to OpenShift.

The private key will then be stored on your PC and you should be able to clone the repository via Git without issue.

You can find full instructions here: https://developers.openshift.com/getting-started/windows.html#client-tools